# Vega graphs only render on hover when using React

Tags: reactjs, vega, vega-lite

I'm attempting to embed a Vega-Lite graph into a React.js application as follows:

```
class ClusterDistribution extends Component {
  createPlot = () => {

    ...

    vegaEmbed(this.node, spec, { actions: false }).then(res => {
      res.view.insert("myData", myData);
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createPlot();
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={node => (this.node = node)} />;
  }
}
```

The data loads well, but there is an odd behavior where it will only draw the bars when I hover as seen in this video:

[show on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdP0i.gif)

Any thoughts on why this may be happening would be great!

Comment: Did you see [react-vega](http://vega.github.io/react-vega/)?

Comment: I hadn't, I changed it to use that API and it works great, thank you! Not sure how it fixes it though.